# AWS cloudfront not working with custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to use cloudfront for static website s3 with my custom domain.
Following are the steps I followed:

1) Setup a s3 bucket (say, `example.com`) and enabled static website hosting on it.

2) Also setup a s3 bucket (`www.example.com`) which redirects to `example.com`.

3) In route 53, added a hosted zone (example.com) and added the record sets.

4) After this, http://example.com works for me.

Now I am trying to add cloudfront to it. I added the following steps:

5) From Amazon Certificate Manager, added a certificate for `www.example.com` and got it verified (added to Route 53 DNS, it was verified automatically after some time).

6) Created a cloudfront distribution with following settings:

```
   Domain Origin: www.example.com
   Origin Protocol Policy: HTTP Only
   Alternate Domain Name: www.example.com
   SSL Certificate: Selected from ACM
```

When I try to launch: `https://example.com` or `https://www.example.com`, the site doesn't load. `http://example.com` does load, but I am not sure if cloudfront is actually working on this or not. Also why is https not loading?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To setup the S3 bucket behind the CF distribution WITH SSL you need to:

1. Setup S3 bucket `example.com` (Block all public access = off, policy https://d.pr/i/KU1Q4z)
2. Create certificate in ACM issued at `example.com` and `*.example.com`(or specific subdomain at will), validate it
3. Create CF distribution
4. Set created CF alternate domain names to: `example.com` `*.example.com` (other subdomain here)
5. Use custom SSL certificate (previously created and validated)
6. Create/change default origin, to: `example.com.s3-website-AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com` with origin protocol policy `HTTP Only`
7. CF Default origin behaviour should be more-less like this: https://d.pr/i/h6PrG6
8. In Route 53 set CF A ALIAS for `example.com` and CNAME for `*.example.com` (or other subdomain) pointing at `CF_DISTRIBUTION_ID.cloudfront.net`

Comment: alternatively, [this](https://tynick.com/blog/05-30-2019/how-to-create-s3-static-website-with-https-its-so-easy/) is a more detailed (but slightly old) step-by-step tutorial

Answer (score 2):

you need to go into rt 53 and point the domain at your cloudfront distribution.  It won't appear as an option unless you've set the domain as an alternate domain in the distribution settings. Also, that cert won't work for anything except www.example.com, meaning example.com is excluded. you need a cert that includes example.com and www.example.com (or *.example.com to cover all subdomains)

Comment: Thanks, I have already added the CNAME entries into route 53 when I generated the certificate for www.example.com. Do I need to add anything else?

Comment: you excluded the part where you repointed the entry to cloudfront in your steps, but apparently you need something else. Can't say without full steps you followed or the specific error.

Comment: In my route 53, I have an entry for example.com which was pointing to s3 bucket. I now changed it to ****.cloudfront.net. Did you mean the same when you said "you need to go into rt 53 and point the domain at your cloudfront distribution"

Comment: the A record for example.com should be pointed at the cloudfront distribution, that is what i meant.

Comment: But if I point my A record to s3 bucket only and in my cloudfront distribution, I set origin to `www.example.com`, shouldn't that be the same thing?

Comment: not even close, A record must be pointed to the cloudfront distribution. DNS is the first responder in routing

Comment: okay thanks, in that case my domain origin should point to the bucket and not `www.example.com`, right? because not I am getting 403 ERROR after pointing the A record to cloudfront distribution.